# how to set up environment variables in mac terminal and have python scripts pick the variable up effectively?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, environment-variables

I'm using MacOS and working on a python project. 
In my project there is a line:

```
num_workers = int(os.environ.get('NUM_SAS_WORKERS', 1))
```

I want to add `NUM_SAS_WORKERS` in my environment variables and set it to 10 so that my python project can load the value 10 into `num_workers`

I've tried executing this in my terminal:

```
export NUM_SAS_WORKERS=10
```

and I was able to verify that `NUM_SAS_WORKERS = 10` exists by running `printenv` in terminal

But it doesn't work. In my python script `num_workers` is still loaded with 1

How to do it correctly?

Comment: That command (capitalization of `EXPORT` aside) will not create an environment variable with a value of 10. The correct form would be `export NUM_SAS_WORKERS=1` (lowercase `export`, no spaces around the `=`).

Comment: How are you running the code?  Are you typing `python myscript.py` in a command prompt, or are you running a GUI, or something else?

Comment: Environment variables you set in one shell session apply only in that shell session and in processes launched from it. So you need to start your Python script from that same session, if you're not.

Comment: @chepner thanks. it was a typo in my question. I just re-editted it. I used 'export' instead of 'EXPORT'

Comment: It *still* won't initialize `NUM_SAS_WORKERS` to 10 if you include the spaces. In fact, the variable won't even be *defined*; `export` simply marks a *name* to be added to the environment, should a variable by that name exist.

Comment: @chepner my bad. I did `export NUM_SAS_WORKERS=1` in my terminal and were able to see `NUM_SAS_WORKERS=1` in the printed list when I execute `printenv` . Sorry for all the typos in the question edit.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to access the `NUM_SAS_WORKERS` environment variable in the Python shell, run this command from your terminal:

```
NUM_SAS_WORKERS=10 python
```

And once in the Python shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> int(os.environ.get('NUM_SAS_WORKERS', 1))
10
```

If you want to access it in a file, very similar:

```
NUM_SAS_WORKERS=10 python yourfile.py
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set up environment variables from the terminal command it gets erased as soon as you close that terminal. To set up and keep them you have to update them in `.bash_profile` file which resides in the home directory as a hidden file. Follow the below commands to update it.

Open terminal

```
cd ~
```

(To take you to the home directory of the mac)

```
open -a "Visual Studio Code" .bash_profile
```

( To open `.bash_profile` file, in the place of "Visual Studio Code" you can use any text editor name)

Now, `.bash_profile` will be opened and there you can set your environment variables and save it.

Example:

```
NUM_SAS_WORKERS=10
```

Now run `echo $[NUM_SAS_WORKERS]` in terminal to read that

After performing the above steps some times still environment variables not available to read in your python project/file. In such cases, you have to restart or log off and log in to your machine that can fix the issue.

To check whether the environment variable is available to your python code run the below script in your python console. This should print all your environment variables.

```
import os 
print(os.eviron)
```